# fglrx causes black screen

Tags: fglrx

i recently installed ubuntu 14.04 directly off usb thumbdrive and it works fine, besides not locating drivers for my x99a mothrboard wifi in the update drivers section

it did however locate my gpu's drivers (3x390x) but when i update these drivers using the update or the standard fglrx and do a reboot it causes the black screen or the ubuntu screen to hang

im going to try and change the settings to nomodeset and the splash in the grub file, hopefully this will work as i dont want to use the standard drivers

any information would be greatly appreciated